# Saving ONLY xml header in xml document throws error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-declaration

I'm trying to use the following code to create a basic xml document with ONLY a header.

```
XDeclaration xmlDec = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no");
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(xmlDec);
XDocument.Save("c:\myxml.xml");
```

When creating an xml file I create a basic xml header and try to save the xml document with ONLY the header but I get the following error on the `Save` method (last line)...

> Token EndDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document.

I think it has to do with the fact there is no XML data after the declaration and I'm trying to save it.  But all I want to save is the declaration.  Is that not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid XML document must have a root element.  This behavior is correct.

The definition of a well-formed XML document can be read at: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed

Comment: I just ended up checking if `xmlDoc.Root != null` before I do the save.  I just will not generate an xml document with only a header I guess. - Thanks, I'll accept as soon as the system lets me.  ;)